# Getting the distance from an element and top of the document

Tags: javascript, scroll, closures

I'm trying to get the distance from the top of an element and the top of the page every time the user scrolls. I got it to work but when you scroll, it says the distance hasn't changed. I tried to solve this with a closure but I am not really great with closures. Theres a demo of what I have so far here: http://addisonbean.com/test/ it logs the distance in the console.

I know there may be an easier way to do this, but I'm would really like to know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

And this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FitGird</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fitgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <h1 class="fg12">Addison Bean.</h1>

    <div class="row">
    <h2>Article</h2>
    <hr class="fg6">
    <hr class="fg6 hidden">
    <p class="fg6">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. </p>
    <p class="fg6">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <p class="fg6">3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. </p>
    <p class="fg6">4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <p class="fg6">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. </p>
    <p class="fg6">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <p class="fg6">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. </p>
    <p class="fg6">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <p class="fg6">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. </p>
    <p class="fg6">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <p class="fg6">5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. </p>
    <p class="fg6">6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, facilis, quo ab architecto veniam ducimus error porro molestiae numquam harum suscipit quae doloremque ullam libero consequuntur mollitia sit doloribus blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ut, saepe quia nam nesciunt delectus sequi incidunt quam amet eaque nostrum blanditiis laboriosam magni minima eveniet culpa dolore sit fugit. </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
    function makeScrollOffset(el) {
        function getWindowOffset() {
        var woff = el.getBoundingClientRect().top,
            soff = window.pageYOffset;

        var dist = Math.round(woff + soff);
        console.log(dist);
    }

    return getWindowOffset;
}

window.onscroll = makeScrollOffset(elem);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok sorry, I will fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code it should be:

`var dist = Math.round(woff-soff);`

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TpGsY/3/)

Comment: Its saying `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getScroll'`

Comment: Why doesn't just adding the pageYOffset work? document.body.scrollTop and window.pageYOffset are always the same, so why do I have to add them for it to change? Sorry, this confuses me.

Comment: You are right I missed that when I was thinking with `getscroll()`.  What you had was almost enought just you should have` var dist = Math.round(soff-woff);` I updated my answer and fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/TpGsY/2/)

Comment: I was thinking more about your question, and there was one thing wrong in my answer. I am tired :) will sleep now. Here is the last version: http://jsfiddle.net/TpGsY/3/

Answer (score 0):

this works very well and returns the distance:

```
window.onscroll = function ()
{
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top);
}
```

note that negative number means the selected elements is above the viewport's top line and positive numbers means under this line. if you get the number 0, the element's top is perfectly aligned with the viewport's top line.

Comment: I was wanting the distance from the top of the html document, not the window